# How to plot coordinates over a shape file in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, r-sf, geom-point

a little new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated. I've loaded a shapefile of all the countries in the world and plotted it. However, I'm having trouble adding a bunch of points from coordinates to the plot. Any help in how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Code so far

```r
MeteoriteData <- read.csv("C:/Users/ChaseDickson_/Desktop/College/AERO 689/Semester Project/Meteorite Landings.csv")
MeteoriteData$lat <- as.factor(MeteoriteData$lat)
MeteoriteData$long <- as.factor(MeteoriteData$long)

world <- st_read("C:/Users/ChaseDickson_/Desktop/College/AERO 689/Semester Project/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp")

world <- st_transform(world, crs = 4326)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world) +
  theme_bw()
```

This returns the plot that is attached.

[image]

I've tried using

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(data = MeteoriteData, aes(x = lat, y = long)
```

but that doesn't seem to work as it gives me this error

```
Error in `calc_limits_bbox()`:
! Scale limits cannot be mapped onto spatial coordinates in `coord_sf()`
ℹ Consider setting `lims_method = "geometry_bbox"` or `default_crs = NULL`.
```

Comment: Your `geom_point` call is missing the closing parenthesis, not sure if that's a copy/paste issue or if you're missing it in your real code.

Comment: Can you provide more details about MeteoriteData? Looks like you've got your X and Y round the wrong way. X should typically be longitude, and Y should be latitude.

Comment: @StewartMacdonald makes an excellent point. I see something else questionable: why did you change the lat and long of `Meteorite Data` to `factor` with the `as.factor` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three issues I can see with your code:

1/

`MeteoriteData$lat <- as.factor(MeteoriteData$lat)`

Do you need to convert your lat and long data to factors? I've never seen that done before and I suspect it will only lead to trouble.

2/

`geom_point(data = MeteoriteData, aes(x = lat, y = long)`

Looks like you've got your x/y and long/lat around the wrong way. x should be long and y should be lat.

3/

As r2evans says, you need a closing parenthesis on this line:

`geom_point(data = MeteoriteData, aes(x = lat, y = long)`

Try this code:

```
require('sf')

# Read in data from .csv file
MeteoriteData <- read.csv("C:/Users/ChaseDickson_/Desktop/College/AERO 689/Semester Project/Meteorite Landings.csv")

# Convert these points to an SF object, specifying the X and Y
#  column names, and supplying the CRS as 4326 (which is WGS84)
MeteoriteData <- st_as_sf(MeteoriteData, coords=c('long', 'lat'), crs=4326)

# Read in the world shape file and convert it to the same CRS
world <- st_read("C:/Users/ChaseDickson_/Desktop/College/AERO 689/Semester Project/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp")
world <- st_transform(world, crs = 4326)

# Plot it
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world) +
  geom_sf(data = MeteoriteData) +
  theme_bw()
```

Note: I don't have access to your data files so this code is from memory and untested but should get you on the right path.